# Docker start não sobe container

Tags: docker

Não estou conseguindo startar meu container, sempre tenho que reiniciar meu pc para poder subi-lo novamente. Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado para que mesmo quando ele caia eu consiga subir ele novamente sem ter que reiniciar o pc, no print abaixo tem os comandos que tentei executar.

**Resumindo, queria saber como posso startar um container "morto".**

[image: print do CMD]

**fiz o comando:**

> docker restart dbtest

**e o retorno foi:**

> Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container dbtest: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dbtest (af1a00ef5c1fb2653d64f5dd5fe028108d71288daa2e3c3edf6a37ba5eee80bc): Error starting userland proxy: /forwards/expose/port returned unexpected status: 500

Comment: Tu não precisa parar o container para iniciá-lo de novo?

Comment: **C:\Users\user>`docker stop dbtest`**
dbtest

**C:\Users\user>`docker start dbtest`**
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dbtest (889886a2a8e0b13ad629dc18699cbcd76033cae5f081108c32056c5c532a4558): Error starting userland proxy: /forwards/expose/port returned unexpected status: 500
Error: failed to start containers: dbtest

Comment: Acabei de parar ele e tentei subir novamente e continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: Achei [essa](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277) issue, não sei se ajuda, pelo o que eu vi, o pessoal só consegue resolver após restartar o docker